# Identify objects in an array created from a for-loop

Tags: java, swing

I have a project that deals with a three panels populated with jbuttons. The jbuttons are created from a for-loop and I was too lazy to recreate a class that has a jpanel populated with jbuttons because it conflicts with my actionlisteners.
Lets say I have three panels each populated with the code:

```
 JPanel panel109 = new JPanel(); //113, 115 for the other two
 roomPanel.add(panel109);
 for(int j = 0; j < 6*28; j++) {
    btn[j] = new JButton();
    btn[j].setName("a" + j);
    btn[j].setBackground(Color.white);
    btn[j].setText("");
    btn[j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,9));
    btn[j].addActionListener(this);
    panel109.add(btn[j]);
}
```

For each panel, how do I identify each btn[] created? I wanted to serialize each button after the user specifies datas to change the button's color, tool tip text and etc. Pretty much I just want to know how to access the buttons I created since three panels use the same loop.
The serialization of all the buttons are from a "store" button, and then "restore" if I want to restore from a file created from it.

Store code:

```
JButton btnStore = new JButton("Store");
    btnStore.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream("myFile"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i=0;i<6*28;i++){
                //deregister
                btn[i].removeActionListener(this);//Heres my problem,
                //serialize                    //I Don't know how to access 
                try {                         //the buttons created from the
                    out.writeObject(btn[i]); //three loops.
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    out.flush();
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                //register
                btn[i].addActionListener(this);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: first of all you should http://stackoverflow.com/mcve your example, second if you are using radio buttons then use JRadioButton() ... You can also use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#ListDialog as a starting example since you are picking whole host of buttons

Comment: oops, I messed up on what type of buttons

Comment: @kfloresmx5 you're accessing `JButton[] btn` inside the `ActionListener`, shall we guess it's a class member (or a `final` local variable)? You can't add the same object to multiple containers (`JPanel`) unless you create a new array for each one. The scope of those variables are important, especially when you want to retrieve them somewhere else...

Comment: Its declared as a private variable, but when I test out the ActionListener, the properties for each JButtons are unique. Therefore it works, but the only problem is accessing or identifying each button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JPanel.putClientProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) to store the `JButton[]`:

```
panel109.putClientProperty("btn", btn);
```

then access it by

```
JButton[] btn = (JButton[])panel109.getClientProperty("btn");
```

You could also use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (which is what `putClientProperty()` is using in the end, though it's a more general `Map<Object,Object>`):

```
Map<JPanel,JButton[]> mapPanelButtons = new HashMap<>();
mapPanelButtons.put(panel109, btn);
...
JButton[] btn = mapPanelButtons.get(panel109);
```

Edit: from your edit with the Store button code, I think you would be better off subclassing `JPanel` to include the `JButton[]` as a member and get direct access anywhere. Laziness is good when it helps you figure out the quickest approach, not the dirtiest ;)
That said, you could be using `getClientProperty()` in your Store button action listener code like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ...
    JButton[] btn = (JButton[])panel109.getClientProperty("btn");
    for (int i=0;i<6*28;i++){ // You might want to use btn.length instead of 6*28
        // ... rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I added my "store" button code, and I'm quite confused on how your answer would be incorporated in the loop.

Comment: @kfloresmx5 you can also save the `JPanel` in each instance of the `JButton`: `btn[j].putClientProperty("panel", panel109)` and retrieve it in the `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < roomPanel.size(); i++) {
    JPanel panel = roomPanel[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < numButtons; j++) {
            btn[i][j] = new JButton();
            btn[i][j].setName(i +"-"+ j);
            btn[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
            btn[i][j].setText("");
            btn[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,9));
            btn[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(btn[i][j]);
    } 
}
```

Assuming `roomPanel` is your list of panels.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question, like I'm not trying to populate a panel again but I want to find a way to access the identifier of the buttons in the loop so I can serialize it after the user edits them.

Comment: You can represent your buttons as a two dimensional array, first dimension being the panel, second the button. Otherwise, I may be totally misunderstanding your problem here.

Comment: Yeah my question is a bit confusing, but I added my "store" button code to show what I do in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately ended up creating 3 different JButton[] arrays for each panel respectively to make things simpler and to meet the deadline, but honestly I think there's a more simpler way to do it.

```
JPanel panel109 = new JPanel();
JButton[] btnOne = new JButton();
for(int j = 0; j < 6*28; j++) {
    btnOne[j] = new JButton();
    btnOne[j].setName("a" + j);
    btnOne[j].setBackground(Color.white);
    btnOne[j].setText("");
    btnOne[j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,9));
    btnOne[j].addActionListener(this);
    panel109.add(btnOne[j]);
}

JPanel panel115 = new JPanel();
JButton[] btnTwo = new JButton();
for(int j = 0; j < 6*28; j++) {
    btnOne[j] = new JButton();
    btnTwo[j].setName("b" + j);
    btnTwo[j].setBackground(Color.white);
    btnTwo[j].setText("");
    btnTwo[j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,9));
    btnTwo[j].addActionListener(this);
    panel115.add(btnTwo[j]);
}
....
```

This makes each array of JButtons unique to itself and can be accessed more easily.